# Magento 2.1.17 product imported but product images not show

Tags: product, import, product-images, csv

I want to import product in Magento 2.1.17 product imported but images show error -

> Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s): 1,2.

I import product using localhost.
/JD0068-A-1.jpg 
I used this path for image

Comment: To import images what you have did?

Comment: Please post some example image URL which you are trying to assign and please check if it directly accessible via URL or not.

Comment: did you defined from where to take images while importing?

Comment: you need to defined path of directory from where images to take. https://prnt.sc/nh6l57

Comment: Yes  I defined path but show same error

Comment: which path you use for Images file directory

Answer (score 0):

For Importing the image using **CSV** file just provide the image name into your csv into the fields with name base_image, small_image, thumbnail_image, swatch_image

You can simply have the csv file structure something like this

```
SKU | product_websites | base_image | small_image | thumbnail_image | swatch_image
ABC | product_web_code | base_i.jpg | small_i.jpg | thumbnail_i.jpg | swatch_i.jpg
```

In the **`Images File Directory`** provide the path to the images something like **pub/product/image** or **var/images**

Click on the check data button for the data validation & then if everything is okay click on the import button.

> Note: At the time of import Magento will look for the images from this
>   place **`Magento_root/{path-you-provide}/image.jpg`**
>
> In the above example it can be
>   **`Magento_root/pub/product/image/image.jpg`** or
>   **`Magento_root/var/images/image.jpg`** as per your given path.
>
> You can also provide the external link for the image download but it
>   is suggested to use your own server so that the downloading & copying
>   of file will not end up with an error of execution time out & again
>   produce the error as you have faced earlier.

Comment: But the import path images is pub/media/import
I put all images in pub/media/import folder

Comment: Try to import in the group of 10-10 first & then gradually increase it it can be because of the copying speed of your system so the execution_time gets exceeded try to increase the php execution time from the php.ini file